# Can I access AngularJS module config values in the template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a special value I would like to access in the `home.tpl.html` template. Can this be done as a `{{magicHappened.mySpecialValue}}`, and if so, how? The value is the final argument in `state()`.

Of course, if there is a better way, please let me know.

```
angular.module('myModule', [
  'ui.router'
])
.config(function homeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: '/app/home/home.tpl.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      pageTitle: 'Home',
      mySpecialValue: 'thisValueHere'
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `data` for your configuration. See: [Attach Custom Data to State Objects](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)

```
.config(function homeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: '/app/home/home.tpl.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      pageTitle: 'Home',
      data: {
         mySpecialValue: 'thisValueHere'
     } 
  });
```

And then in your controller

```
.controller('HomeCtrl',
    [        '$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope,   $state) {            
        $scope.mySetting = $state.current.data.mySpecialValue;
        ...
```

which could be on your view like `{{mySetting}}`

Comment: Yes, that was more or less how I did it. :) I used $scope.on($stateChangeSuccess, function(event, toState){//very similar to your code}); Thank you very much for the link. That is ideal.